# Buttons in Javascript not working after some js changes in html

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

There is a following problem with JS and jquery. During one of the events happening on the page:

```
task = $("#id").html();
$("#video_id").html(task);
$("#id").html("");
```

After that, the buttons from #id doesn't work in #video_id.

I've tried to send the data from #video_id back to the old place and process the events there

```
task = $("#video_id").html();
$("#id").html(task);
$("#video_id").html("");
```

But after that stopped working all buttons inside the #id.

How to make the elements within the task correctly processed when transferred to #video_id?

Comment: Can you post the code for those buttons? html and event handlers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're binding the events to the buttons with jquery you would need to bind the events during the copy process for this to work.

Or use the $(document).on() method...

```
<div id="one"><button class="two">test</button></div>
<div id="three"></div>

$(document).on('click', '.two', function(){
    alert("test");
    var test = $('#one').html();
    $('#three').html(test);                
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/5EwuX/7/

This will bind the event to new elements dynamically added to the DOM.